# Tag Input in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, tags, textfield, look-and-feel

We have multiple tag input in JS ( picture )

[image: Tag Input on JS]

I wanted to know is there any default Java Swing facility to do it within JTextField or JTextArea. Is there any custom look-and-feel library or plugin to do so ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I'm a bit confused, Are you asking for a web library (js = Java Script) or for a library to do so with Java? (or Applet? (Java and Web))

Comment: Are you looking for a lookahead functionality? http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TextFieldLookAheadExample.htm

Comment: @quant : I am trying to implement the exact feature using Java Swing. No JS in here. Pure Java. I used the example for the sake of understanding.

Comment: @Hirak : not lookahead. I am trying to add multiple tag, if autocomplete is found, that will be bonus.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such component. You should be able to make your own easy enough:

1. Start with a JPanel using a FlowLayout and add a JTextField to the panel
2. Then you can add an ActionListener to the text field. When ever Enter is pressed you create a "TagComponnent" and add the component to the start of the panel and remove the text from the text field.
3. This "TagComponent" may just be a simple panel that contains a label (for the text) and a button (to remove) the component from the panel.